# Custom template for sub-sub-categories

Tags: categories, templates

I'm trying to add a custom template for all posts in a sub-sub-category. I mean like

```
Category --> SubCategory Level 1 --> Subcategory Level 2 --> post
```

I'm using the following code:

```
 <?php
  $post = $wp_query->post;

  if (cat_is_ancestor_of( 42, $cat ) ) {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/services_template.php');
  } else {
      include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-default.php');
  }
?>
```

However, it only shows a blank page, both in the sub-sub-cat post as well as all teh other posts. I double checked and the templates are there, so I guess there's something wrong with my code, but can't figure what

edit: I have several CPT single pages named `single-{CPT-slug}.php` . Is it possible this is affecting things?

Comment: Do you debugging turned on? Where have you added this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of include(), use get_template_part()

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

`<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;
if (cat_is_ancestor_of( 42, $cat ) ) {
  get_template_part( 'services', 'template' )
} else {
  get_template_part( 'single', 'default' );
}
?>`

If you create those files and use get_template_part(), then within those files you can set them up to display posts however you see fit. Take a look at the Underscores theme on github, the archive.php file has a good example of using get_template_part() within the loop -

https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/archive.php

Here is a link as well to one of the template_parts for Underscores to see how they set it up within that file -

https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/template-parts/content.php

Tom Mcfarlin explains this extremely well here -

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-and-require-files-and-templates-in-wordpress--wp-26419

Response to your edits: Your single-{CPT-slug}.php templates should not cause any issues with this.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: I updated my original comment with the code for this.

Comment: Some more details are needed to fully understand and answer this. What file is this code in? Is this a page template, or is this a single-{CPT slug}.php file or an archive-{CPT slug}.php file? Turning on debug mode would also be helpful to help answer this.